# Color picker in listpicker using

Tags: windows-phone-8, color-picker, listpicker

I am trying to use color picker on Windows Phone 8, but I cannot see colors.  I do not understand where I am making a mistake.

This is my PivotPage code:

```
  string[] colorNames =
        {
         "GreenYellow","Lime","Chartreuse","LimeGreen","SpringGreen","LightGreen"
        }
  uint[] uintColors =
        {
          0xFFFFFF00,0xFFFFE135,0xFFFFFF66,0xFFF8DE7E,0xFF008000,0xFF008A00
        }

  List<ColorItem> item = new List<ColorItem>();
         for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
         {
             item.Add(new ColorItem() { Text = colorNames[i], Color =  ConvertColor(uintColors[i]) });
         };


        listPicker.ItemsSource = item; //Fill ItemSource with all colors

    }

    private Color ConvertColor(uint p)
    {

         byte A = (byte)((p & 0xFF000000) >> 24);
         byte R = (byte)((p & 0x00FF0000) >> 16);
         byte G = (byte)((p & 0x0000FF00) >> 8);
         byte B = (byte)((p & 0x000000FF) >> 0);

         return Color.FromArgb(A, R, G, B); ;
    }
```

This is my ColorItem Class:

```
class ColorItem
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public Color Color { get; set; }
}
```

Like this:

[image]

And this:

[image]

Comment: meaning of title is not clear.

Comment: Sorry gonzobrains. My English is not perfect.

Answer (score 0):

you left out the xaml that actually builds the coloured squares. see [link](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Custom_Color_Picker_for_Windows_Phone)

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
x:Class="CustomColorsPicker.ColorPickerPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
mc:Ignorable="d"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="False"
xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:CustomColorsPicker.Converters"
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True">

<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <converters:ColorToBrushConverter x:Key="ColorToBrushConverter"/>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">

        <ListBox Name="listBox" SelectionChanged="lstColor_SelectionChanged">
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <toolkit:WrapPanel/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel x:Name="item" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="12, 6 0, 6">
       <Rectangle Fill="{Binding Color, Converter={StaticResource ColorToBrushConverter}}" 
                            Width="100" Height="100" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>

    </Grid>
</Grid>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```